# Printable Esri symbol sets, a.k.a. style references

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology

Does anyone know of good printable documents of the as-shipped Esri symbol sets, also called [Style References](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_symbols_and_styles/00s600000006000000/)?

The new with Arcgis 10 ability to search symbol sets is a great boon, but one can still only find things for which you know the keywords for, and only few so many at a time on screen. I find hard copy of things like this much easier and faster to look through and locate the right one for the map at hand.

For example this morning I was looking for a good glacial moraine symbol and searching the style sets didn't locate anything relevant. So I decided to bite the bullet and build my own. In the process I went browsing through the *...\Desktop10\Styles* directory and discovered several pictures I've never noticed represented in any styles that would be perfect for the project I'm working on. Since they're here they very likely already exist in a symbol set and I'd be wasting my time creating them anew. Thus the desire for a printed set to help me find them.

In previous versions there is a developer sample called [Style Dump](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/cartography/styles/style_dump/a06be6ca-0d38-4bbd-a20a-40331fd61527.htm), but it doesn't work in Arcgis 10 (and the results were pretty crude and wasted paper anyway).